# How to plot and save an image using python just like in matlab?

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib, colormap

I have a code in Matlab which reads data from a txt file and, after some manipulations with that data, generates a 20x20 array that is used to plot an image as follows:
[image]

I needed to transcribe this code to Python for reasons of optimization and project need. Until the phase of generating the matrix is correct, but I can not generate the same images, because they are with different scales and colors as follows:
[image]

The following is the code snippet in Matlab that plots the image:

```
figure
image(H1,'CDataMapping','scaled')
colormap;
saveas(gcf,'d1.jpg');
```

And here's the code snippet in Python:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(H1)
plt.gcf().savefig('d1.jpg')
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

I just need to plot the image with the same resolution (875 x 656) and change the color to be more similar.

Right now, I thank those who help! :D

Comment: The MATLAB figure uses the Parula color map, which is copyrighted by The MathWorks. As I understand it, you cannot recreate that exact same color map outside of MATLAB without infringing on copyright.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resolution is controlled by two parameters `figsize` which accepts a tuple that represents the size of the figure in inches and `dpi` controls the dots-per-inch of the figure. These two would go into your `subplots` argument:

```
ax, fig = plt.subplots(figsize=(x, y), dpi=z)
```

where `x` and `y` would be the desired width and height of the figure and `z` would be the desired dpi.

As for the colors, you need to select a different **colormap**. First choose the colormap you want (matplotlib available colormaps can be found [here](https://matplotlib.org/users/colormaps.html)). Then pass it into the `cmap` argument of `imshow`, like this:

```
ax.imshow(H1, cmap=c)
```

where `c` is a string containing the *name* of the colormap.